# ListView(Populated By Parse.com) |OnItemClicked to get objectId

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

I am populating a listView from Parse.com using ParseQueryAdapter. The listView populates with some selected data from every object from my parse class. What I want is, when a listItem is clicked, I should get the object Id of the clicked item, so that , I can use that objectId to load more details of that Object in another activity.

My Parse Adapter:

```
@Override
    public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (v == null) {
            v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.list_feed_item, null);
        }

        super.getItemView(object, v, parent);

        // Add and download the image
        ParseImageView propImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.propThumbnail);
        ParseFile imageFile = object.getParseFile("Image1");
        if (imageFile != null) {
            propImage.setParseFile(imageFile);
            propImage.loadInBackground();
        }

        // Add the title view
        TextView priceTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.priceField);
        priceTextView.setText("Total Price:"+object.getString("TotalPrice"));

        TextView superTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.superAreaFieldList);
        superTextView.setText("Super Area:"+object.getString("SuperArea"));

        TextView priceUnitTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.priceUnitFieldList);
        priceUnitTextView.setText("@"+ object.getString("PriceUnit"));

        TextView locationTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.locationList);
        locationTextView.setText("Locality:"+object.getString("Locality"));

        TextView cityTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cityList);
        cityTextView.setText("City:"+object.getString("City"));

        TextView bhkTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bhkInfoList);
        bhkTextView.setText(object.getString("BedRooms")+"BHK");

        TextView projNameTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.projName);
        projNameTextView.setText("By:"+object.getString("ProjName"));

        TextView objIdTextView =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listObjId);
        objIdTextView.setText(object.getString("objectId"));






        // Add a reminder of how long this item has been outstanding
        /*TextView timestampView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        timestampView.setText(object.getCreatedAt().toString());*/
        return v;
    }
```

As u can see, what I tried to do is, I loaded the objectId in a textView which is Invisible on the ListItem.

My ListActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rent_listing_feed);

        // Initialize main ParseQueryAdapter
        mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, "PropertyDetails");
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("TotalPrice");
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("SuperArea");
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("PriceUnit");
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("Locality");
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("City");
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("BedRooms");
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("ProjName");
        mainAdapter.setImageKey("Image1");
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("objectId");


        // Initialize the subclass of ParseQueryAdapter
        rexovoAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this);

        // Initialize ListView and set initial view to mainAdapter
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listFeedFromParse);
        listView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
        mainAdapter.loadObjects();

        if (listView.getAdapter() == mainAdapter) {
            listView.setAdapter(rexovoAdapter);
            rexovoAdapter.loadObjects();
        } else {
            listView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
            mainAdapter.loadObjects();
        }








       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               ParseObject parseObject = rexovoAdapter.getItem(position);
              // parseObject.get("objectId");

               Intent intent=new Intent(RentListingFeed.this, RentListingListItemActivity.class);
               intent.putExtra("ObjectId",parseObject.getString("objectId"));
               startActivity(intent);
           }
       });
}
}
```

Then I tried to get the objectId and send it to the next Activity through Intent. But, ObjectId is not being received in the next Activity. 
??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: why can't you store the `objectId` in a variable rather than in an invisible `TestView` ?

Comment: I want to get the objectId of only that object which is being clicked in the listview. Can you tell me how I can do that in the OnItemClick of my listView?

Comment: @asdec90: what  value you are getting in `parseObject.getString("objectId")` on onItemClick ?

Comment: I am getting a null value !

Comment: Have you used the [`getObjectId()`](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#getObjectId%28%29) method?

Comment: How should I use the getObjectId() in the OnItemClick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to get the `objectId`?

Consider using the [`getObjectId()`](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#getObjectId%28%29) method.

> Accessor to the object id. An object id is assigned as soon as an
>   object is saved to the server.

The reason you are getting a null is maybe because the `ParseObject` that you are using was never stored on the server. Maybe you are accessing the locally stored objects?

> I want to get the objectId of only that object which is being clicked
>   in the listview.

Store your `ParseObject`s in a `List` that you can index into depending on which item was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Customize and try the following code to implement onclick of listview row

```
   public class Myadapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener,OnBufferingUpdateListener{

String currentid=null;

    @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              View vi = convertView;

             crntposition=position;

              if(convertView==null){

                  Context context=arg2.getContext();
                   inflater = ( LayoutInflater )activity.
                           getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

             vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.songlistrow, null);

            TextView objIdTextView =(TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.listObjId);
        objIdTextView.setText(object.getString("objectId"));
objIdTextView.setTag(crntposition+"%"+object.getString("objectId"));
         }

    // your code 

     vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(crntposition,objIdTextView.setTag));

            return vi;

        }

    private class OnItemClickListener  implements View.OnClickListener {
            private int mPosition;

            OnItemClickListener(int position,String tag) {

                mPosition = position;
currentid=tag.substring(tag.indexOf("%"),tag.length()-1);//here you will getthe objectid

                //System.out.println("pos"+mPosition);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


              System.out.println("current position"+mPosition);// you can use the position here I have just printed it

            }

        }
```